# Visual Studio always rebuilds solution if packaging UWP

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, uwp, build

I want the deployable package to include modified binary (copy protected) files.
To do that I first build the solution in Release.
Then copy protect the files in the output (bin) folder.
Then create the packages (Publish --> Create App Packages...).

When I package the UWP it rebuilds everything in the background and replaces my copy protected libraries. Although, VS does not show it is building but I just see that the file size is changed and modification date is newed.

How can I prevent the rebuild so that my modified files are included in the package? The app will be deployed by sideloading.

When packaging I select a (self added) Deploy configuration at Configuration Manager to prevent the rebuild but it does not affect the deployment process.

[image: Custom Deploy build configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Add the files to be included in your app to the project in Visual Studio (Project->Add Existing Item...) and set the `Build Action` of them to `Content` and the `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy if newer` in the **Properties Window** (View->Properties Window).

Then they should be included in the output directory when you build.

[Build actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077)

Comment: Your solution would be great if I want a specific file in a project to be copied to the output folder if it has changes. In my case I would like to keep all the .dll files and .exe file the Visual Studio has previously built when creating package from the solution output.

Comment: Where do the DLL files come from? Are you referencing them?

Comment: No. VS solution has many library projects and they are initially built with the solution's startup projects.

Comment: @JPollack: I don't follow. Anyway, to include files as part of the package, you should include them in the project one way or another.